# jQuery mobile events not firing at all

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I'm new to mobile programming and already facing this problem.

When using jQuery mobile, only normal events like "click" work, but not the mobile ones like "tap" or "taphold". What am I missing? I've already found some hints about using the right order when linking the jQuery files but I don't see any mistake there.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/map.css"></link>
<script src="http://open.mapquestapi.com/sdk/leaflet/v0.1/mq-map.js?key=**"></script>
<script src="http://open.mapquestapi.com/sdk/leaflet/v0.1/mq-geocoding.js?key=**"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    loading('show');
    map = L.map('map', {
        layers: MQ.mapLayer(),
        center: [51.137140, 10.239258],
        zoom: 6
    });

    $(document).on("tap", "#map", function(e) {alert("lel");} );
    loading('hide');
};
</script>
```

This works on the other hand:

```
$(document).on("click", "#map", function(e) {alert("lel");} );
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `$(document).on('pageinit', function() { .. ` and not `window.onload` ?

Comment: That didn't change anything unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like tap does not have the long format for '.on'

It only has the format for providing the callback function.  Try

```
$("#map").on("tap",function(e) {alert("lel");} );
```

**EDIT**

It looks like the long form also works fine.  Can you check to see if you have the right library?  I can not download the maps but it seems to work fine on a div.

I'va added tap and taphold.  It's interesting that on a Android Chrome, if click is detected first then tap can be stopped but if tap is detected first, then click always fires afterwards.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vBS1KnKkcQZkF7CP5tsJ?p=preview

Comment: Your snippet pointed me in the right direction. I forgot to link the jquery CSS file. Thanks!